# List of 10 Taxpayers who spent the most

Tags: java

I need to return a List, or a Collection in general, that gives me the 10 taxpayers who spent the most in the entire system. The classes are divided in User, Taxpayer (which extends User) and Expense, and in my main class Main I have a Map holding every single value for Users and Expenses, respectively a `Map<String, User> users` and a `Map<String, Expense> expenses`.

The first step would be to go through the Map of users and check if it's a Taxpayer , then for that Taxpayer get all the Expenses he has done. Inside each expense there's a variable called Value with a getValue method to return the Value.

I've tried to do it but I was having a problem in updating the Collection if the next Taxpayer had a higher sum on Expense values than the one on the "end" of the Collection.

Also, I would prefer if this wasn't done in Java 8 since I'm not very comfortable with it and there's more conditions that I would need to set in the middle of the method.

Edit (what I have until now):

```
public List<Taxpayer> getTenTaxpayers(){
        List<taxpayer> list = new ArrayList<Taxpayer>();
    
        for(User u: this.users.values()){
            if(!u.getUserType()){ // if it is a Taxpayer
                Taxpayer t = (Taxpayer) u;
                double sum = 0;
                for(Expense e: this.expenses.values()){
                    if(t.getNIF().equals(e.getNIFClient())){ //NIF is the code that corresponds to the Taxpayer. If the expense belongs to this Taxpayer, enters the if statement.
                      sum += e.getValue();
                      if(list.size()<10){
                          list.add(t.clone());
                      }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your concrete class. It can be done easily with stream

Comment: Please post your non-working code. It's easier to fix your code than to explain what to do from the very beginning.

Comment: My classes are all in a different Language and contain a huge amount of code already... Not sure how would i do it.

Comment: Post your minimal class, which help you to check for taxPlayer, get the id, get the value. Your input, your output

Comment: Posted what i have until now, hope it helps, if not i'll try to post the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, when you already have 10 `Taxpayers` in your list, you are struggling on how to then add another taxpayer to the list to maintain a only to top 10 "spenders"

One way to approach this is to gather the expenses of all your `Taxpayers` and add them **all** to your list. Then sort the list in reverse order by the amount they have spent. Then just get the first 10 entries from the list.

You could do this using the [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method defining your own custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Something like:

```
List<Taxpayer> taxpayers =...

Collections.sort(taxpayers, new Comparator<Taxpayer>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Taxpayer o1, Taxpayer o2)
    {
        return o1.sum - o2.sum; // using your correct total spent here
        // or to just sort in reverse order
        // return o2.sum - o1.sum;
    }
});
```

Or if `Taxpayer` implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) you can just use

```
Collections.sort(taxpayers)
```

Then reverse

```
Collections.reverse(taxpayers)
```

Then get top 10

```
List<Taxpayer> top10 = taxpayers.subList(0, 10);
```

To be more efficient though you could just define the comparator to sort the list in reverse order - then you don't need to reverse the list - just get the top 10.

Comment: That's great! Thank you.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making the Comparator. How do i get the Value on each expense to add to the sum? Because what i want to sort is the Taxpayer, but the actual sort parameter belongs to the Expense class.

Comment: You could have a field in your taxpayer for total spent, then after you have looped through the expenses to total them all for that taxpayer, set the total to that taxpayer and then use that for your sorting

Comment: Sounds good. Also what would i need to do besides putting my class Taxpayer implementing Comparable to get the comparator working?

Comment: I got a IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 10. I only have like 4 taxpayers yet on my system, is it because of this?

Comment: Yes, you will need to first check that your array size is > 10